# Apache ant 1.9.4 compatibility with Java 1.8

Tags: java, apache, ant, java-8, build.xml

Is Ant 1.9.4 compatible with Java 1.8?
The [ant documentation](https://ant.apache.org/faq.html) is not very clear: it just says that it is compatible with a minimum version of Java 1.5.
How can I be sure that it is compatible with java 1.8?
Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This Ant Java Version Table](https://ant.apache.org/faq.html#java-version) indicates that `ant 1.9.x` needs a minimum version of 1.5. As Java takes great pains to maintain backwards compatibility, it would be extraordinary for an incompatibility to occur. Ant 1.10 requires Java 1.8.

We have been running 1.9.6 for many months with Java 8 without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here](http://ant.apache.org/)

`We recommend using 1.10.x unless you are required to use versions of Java prior to Java8 during the build process`

To me this reads as *not supported* and might suddenly break.

Comment: Perhaps it is too early for me and I am missing something, but the text at that link also says, "The 1.9.x releases require Java5 at runtime and 1.10.x requires Java8 at runtime." Therefore 1.9.x will work on Java8, but 1.9.x is not receiving new features. As long as the feature set in 1.9.x is sufficient, there is no reason to believe that using Java8 with 1.9.x would be an issue.

Comment: @KevinO you might be right, but the features are the features that ant has  or the features from java-8 that are supported by ant?